# Why 1 is not recognized as real?

Tags: core-language

I'm not understanding smth simple. Why is 1 not recognized as a real number in the second line?

[image]

Comment: This is a structural operation, and the `Head` of `1` is `Integer`, not `Real`.

Comment: See for instance, [Types of Numbers](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TypesOfNumbers.html) and [Specifying Types of Expression in Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SpecifyingTypesOfExpressionInPatterns.html)

Comment: Cases[{1}, _?(# ∈ Reals &)]

Comment: @mathe's suggestion is already very good. When selecting at first level based on a function that returns booleans (`True` or `False`), `Select` is usually a bit quicker: `Select[x, (# \[Element] Reals &)]`.

Comment: Note a subtlety: `0.11518 + 0. I \[Element] Reals` does not evaluate to `True` or `False`.  The condition `Im[z] == 0` is sometimes a safer test, depending on what may be assumed about `z`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are confusing the storage type `Real` with the number class `Reals`.

`Real` describes how the computer is storing the number. It has nothing to do with the class of real numbers, which *Mathematica* calls `Reals`.